# How come Stone-Weierstrass theorem does not imply that in a given interval every continuous function has a power series expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Since for all continuous functions we get a polynomial sequence that uniformly converges to that function? As the degree of polynomial increases it should look like a power series expansion?

Comment: The coefficients of $x^k$ change in the approximating sequence.

Comment: I thought of answering this, but then I noticed Daniel Fischer's comment, which says it all.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed as I post the question. an example might be Bernstein polynomials

Comment: I'd also note that Stone's extension to the Weierstrass Polynomial Approximation theorem generalizes its conclusions beyond the scope of polynomials anyway. Any point-separating real continuous function algebra on any compact $T_2$ space suffices for the approximation (complex algebras must also be self-adjoint).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, but if the approximating sequence is : $P_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k,n}x^k$ then because it convergs uniformaly we can say : $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{k,n}x^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 
 \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{k,n}x^k$. So we have fixed coefficient, because  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{k,n}$ converges. So where am I wrong here ?